# B2C - Custom flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a banking application and decided to use B2C as Microsoft identity provider. In baking world we first identify users through Account Number and SSN/DOB and then user creates his login-id. However, Microsoft does not provide this in B2C. It has sign-in, up, reset and profile edit. I want to integrate Account and SSN validation screen with B2C flow.

Please assist and need guidance. Let me know in case of any questions and clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft AADB2C has two offerings - standard/basic and custom. The five flows you have described are basic flows. Custom flows provide much more capability and power to developers.

Please start with samples and other material using below link
[Get started with custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom)

The kind of functionality you are asking is possible in AADB2C. You will possibly be using [Restful providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom)